# How to start git flow upon trying it in the past...?

Tags: git, git-flow

Sorry for the bad title, but...

I tried git flow on a project I was creating a few months back and found it was nice, but as I was still hacking together the project to be, all distinction between what's main, develop or feature was a bit useless. So I finished the feature I started and continued hacking on *main*.

Now, the release is coming and I wanted to start a release branch, which upon closing would the serve of a git flow style workflow. When I "git flow release start v1.0.0"ed, it created a release branch stemming from where I last tried flow, a few hundred commits back. Obviously, this is not what I had in mind...

So, how could I tell git flow to start the release branch from current HEAD (master)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can checkout your release branch, and tell it to `git merge main`. It should perform a fast-forward with no errors.